# Combine all my custom JS into one single file with dojo build

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I'm having a hard time trying to set up dojo build in my project.

Basically, I have my js folder with all my custom widgets and components. I simply want to combine all javascript files form js folder into one single file.

dojo sources are located outside this folder. The structure looks similar to this:

```
/public
         /prod
               /dojo-1.9
                     /dijit
                     /dojo
                     /dojox
        /js
             myScript1.js                   
             myScript2.js
```

Do you have any idea on how should I configure the package.json and profile.js? The documentation doesn't seem to help since all I am getting is an output folder with the same contents as the js folder (no javascript is merged).

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading this article:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/simpleExample.html

It provides a simplified overview of dojo build system.

Additional there is dojo boilerplate with a sample of folder structure and `profile.js` configuration for quick start here:

https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate

I definitely suggest you to use the boilerplate as start for your project as it simplify a lot initial configurations.